# How to match "[" and "]" in regexp?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, brackets

How to match "[" and "]" in regular expression? 
This one does not work: `[\\[\\]]`
I thought that `\\` enables use of special character. I want to match them inside a class.

Comment: I'm using C++11 regular expressions inside string.

Comment: Note that you don't need to escape everything twice if you use a raw string literal: `R"([\[\]])"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your engine, and on whether you want to match a specific bracket (opening vs. closing), or to match a class of brackets.

- `\[` matches opening bracket
- `\]` matches closing bracket
- `[][]` matches one char that is either an opening or closing bracket (.NET, Perl, PCRE, Python)
- `[]\[]` same as above (Java and the 4 engines above)
- `[[\]]` same as above (JavaScript and the 4 engines above)
- `[\]\[]` same as above (Ruby, all engines)

**Avoiding Backslash Soup**

A handful of languages, such as Java, requires you to escape backslashes in the regex string, leading to `\\[` and other unsightly variations. Fortunately, most languages give you ways to avoid escaping backslashes.

- `"\["` can be used as is in JavaScript, PHP, Perl, Ruby, VB.NET, VBScript
- `@"\["` (verbatim string) in C#
- `r"\["` (raw string) in Python
- `R"(\])"` or `R"foo(\])foo"` in C++11 (raw string literal). A raw string lives between parentheses, which can be surrounded by an optional delimiter (`foo` in the second version).

**Reference**

[Interesting Character Classes](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-interesting-character-classes.html)

Comment: If i use ```\[``` or ```\]```, i'm getting warning about unregonized escape literal.

Comment: @user3811473 It does in some engines, Ruby for instance. This is why I gave all these examples about the different engines.

Comment: @zx81: agreed, I'll leave my answer for extra info but voted up your answer because its more complete :)

Comment: @GermánDiago Saw your edit attemps. Good idea to explain string options. Added a section for this, and took the C++11 from your suggestions after minor edits—thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

`\[` and `]` should work.
In some languages you may have to double escape. (i.e. `\\[` and `]`).

Note: You don't need to escape `]` :)

DEMO: http://regex101.com/r/vP4mQ9/1

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: ```regex_error(error_brack): The expression contained mismached [ and ]```. Regexp: ```\\[]``` (it is inside of string)

Comment: can you provide the text you're trying to match?

Comment: Not really a concrete text. I want know that a form won't contain any "non-name" chars.